# Дженерики чтобы избавиться от повтора кода

Tags: java, generics

Есть Set принимающий в конструкторе массив Numbers и метод summator который складывает все числа из коллекции. Меня смущает, что код для суммирования повторяется... можно ли как то эту задачу решить красивее... возможно с помощью дженериков? Я попробовал написать обобщенный код и параметизировать класс, но в таком виде это также не работает

```
/*
T sum = null;
for (T element : setNumbers)
    sum += element;
return sum;
*/
```

Или нельзя в принципе тут использовать дженерики? и нужно искать красивое решение в работе с Collections или стрим апи, лямбды какие-нибудь.... Подскажите направление хотя бы. Привожу свой код...

```
private Set<Number> numbers;
private Class type;

public MathBox(Number[] numbers){
    if (numbers[0] instanceof Integer) this.type = Integer.class;
    if (numbers[0] instanceof Long) this.type = Long.class;
    if (numbers[0] instanceof Double) this.type = Double.class;
    if (numbers[0] instanceof Float) this.type = Float.class;

    this.numbers = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(numbers));
}

public Number summator() {
    if (type == Integer.class) {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Number element : numbers)
            sum += (Integer) element;
        return sum;
    }

    if (type == Long.class) {
        Long sum = 0L;
        for (Number element : numbers)
            sum += (Long) element;
        return sum;
    }

    if (type == Double.class) {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (Number element : numbers)
            sum += (Double) element;
        return sum;
    }

    if (type == Float.class) {
        Float sum = 0.0F;
        for (Number element : numbers)
            sum += (Float) element;
        return sum;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Преобразуйте коллекцию в числовой поток set.stream().toIntStream(i -> i) и вызовите функцию суммирования .sum()

Comment: Да стрим это хорошо, будет поменьше строк, наверное... но у меня малость другой запрос. Вот если бы можно было бы в этот стрим передавать тип данных (Integer, Double...). Или подставлять его из переменной type в один универсальный код...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, достаточно красивого кода не получится, вследствие того, что в абстрактном классе `Number` не определен метод `sum()`. Он определен лишь в некоторых наследниках(`Integer, Double`), поэтому в Вашем случае без каста и принудительного указания, какой метод использовать, не обойтись.

Можно с помощью Java Stream API реализовать так:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

public class MathBox<T extends Number> {
    private final T[] numbers;
    MathBox(T[] arr){
        numbers = arr;
    }

    public int intSum(){
        return Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToInt(x -> x.intValue()).sum();
    }

    public double doubleSum(){
        return Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToDouble(x -> x.doubleValue()).sum();
    }

    public long longSum(){
        return Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToLong(x -> x.longValue()).sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы попробовал так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MathBox {
    private Set<Number> numbers;
    private Class type;

    public MathBox(Number... numbers) {
        this.numbers = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MathBox(1, 2, 3).sum());
        System.out.println(new MathBox(1.1, 2.2, 3.3).sum());
    }

    public Number sum() {
        Double sum = 0.0;

        for (Number element : numbers)
            sum += Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(element));
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Если тип результата не очень важен.

---

**UPD:** Либо так, это более правильно:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

interface MathBox<T> {
    T sum();
}

public class MathBox2 {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MathBox2.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathBox mathBox = new IntegerMathBox(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(mathBox.sum());
        mathBox = new DoubleMathBox(1.1, 2.1, 3.1);
        System.out.println(mathBox.sum());
    }
}

class IntegerMathBox implements MathBox<Integer> {

    private Integer[] array;

    public IntegerMathBox(Integer... array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer sum() {
        Integer integer = 0;
        for (Integer i : array) {
            integer += i;
        }
        return integer;
    }
}

class DoubleMathBox implements MathBox<Double> {

    private Double[] array;

    public DoubleMathBox(Double... array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    @Override
    public Double sum() {
        Double d = 0.0;
        for (Double dd : array) {
            d += dd;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: интересное решение (превратить в строку, а потом в Double)... но выглядит как костыль ))), тут все же  нужно что то другое

Comment: Добавил вариант )